# Can the system trace function be set in MicroFocus Cobol?

Tags: python, cobol, microfocus

Does MicroFocus Cobol or any other, have a feature equivalent to Python's [sys.settrace()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace)?
The function passed as a parameter to such a tracing function, would be called after the execution of each line of the source code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The short answer is no, but if we know what you want, there may be some resolution - hard to say, for now :-)

Comment: Well, if you're happy, we're happy.:-) If that was all the answer you wanted, why make the question so complex? "How can I trace the flow of a Cobol program using the source line-numbers of paragraphs/SECTIONS, and nothing more complicated that that please?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an exact equivalent, but you can use [READY TRACE](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx20books/atdebu.htm) for debugging.  Enable it with the TRACE compiler directive.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCOBOL supports

```
-ftrace               Generate trace code
                    - Executed SECTION/PARAGRAPH
-ftraceall            Generate trace code
                    - Executed SECTION/PARAGRAPH/STATEMENTS
                    - Turned on by -debug
```

cobc command line options. This isn't quite the same as the Python point of view, but outputs a tracer round on entry to sections, paragraphs and sentences when enabled.  No doubt other compilers will have something equivalent.  Along with the READY TRACE, debugging and >>D other debugging features like those allowed with DECLARATIVES.  http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#declaratives

```
procedure division.
declaratives.
handle-errors section.
    use after standard error procedure on filename-1.
handle-error.
    display "Something bad happened with " filename-1 end-display.
.
helpful-debug section.
    use for debugging on main-file.
help-me.
    display "Just touched " main-file end-display.
.
end declaratives.
```